# How to run one angular app with two urls?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications

Wanted to know is there any way that we can run one angular 6 app on with two rendering URL ?

Example :

www.domain.com/abc1

www.domain.com/abc2

We have two urls that will be using the same application but the difference is whenever abc1 is rendered data shown is different then the abc2.
Both are sharing the same code/application.

Not sure how to do this or that's possible ?

Comment: When you say "the difference is whenever abc1 is rendered data shown is different" - you mean to say, backends are different?

Comment: Otherwise, Angular and Angular Apps don't really care where you deploy and render them. The data comes from backend - or sometimes, based on _configuration_, from different environment files.

Comment: The network calls will be REST calls, But the presenting to user looks like two subdomains and two app but internally its should be same app. Also while navigating between abc1 to abc2 want to avoid page refresh as navigation will be available to navigate vice a versa

Answer (score 0):

If the data comes from backend and the Angular apps differ in datasource you should try this:

```
ng build --prod --base-href "/abc1/"

ng build --prod --base-href "/abc2/"
```

Comment: Would it create two deployment folders ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create different layouts based on the view you want to load.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to the others listed would be to actually use the same app for this, just on different routes.

Say you are listing Todos, but on `/abc1` they com from  `server-1.com/api`, and on `/abc2`, they come from `server-2.com/api`.

You'd first create your app routing module, to capture the "subdomain" (as you called it, although it's actually a virtual directory) part of the url. So, `app-routing.module.ts` has this for routes:

```
const routes = [
  { path: ':subdomain', component: TodosComponent },
];

// and the rest of it.
```

(For simplicity I'm not doing modules here).

So now your TodosComponent simply reads the "subdomain" and fetches stuff from proper backend:

```
class TodosComponent implements OnInit {
    // inject the backend service (or more) and activated route
    constructor(private backend: BackendService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    // on init, get that route param
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            // catch the "subdomain" param
            const subdomain =  params.subdomain;
            // now you'd move this to a service, but here:
            if (subdomain === 'abc1') {
                this.backend.get('http://server-1.com/api').subscribe(...);
            } else if (subdomain === 'abc2') {
                this.backend.get('http://server-2.com/api').subscribe(...);
            } else {
                // add more as needed here.
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now, this would be the same app that would work completely as a SPA as you switch between subdomains.

In the actual app, your app-routing would pass this down to a (lazy) module, this module would have all the components, services etc built so that you can parametrize all the setup with this url segment/route parameter.